# How would I go about fixing this gif?

Tags: gimp, gif, blender, animated-gif

I'm new here so I will do my best to cover all the details.
To start I'm using two programs, Blender and Gimp.
I used Gimp to set up the original images need to build a 3d coin in Blender, used Blender to build and render a 180 rotation of said coin, and went back to Gimp to export it as a gif. Everything has been smooth until I looked at the finished gif.

[image: Text]

As you can see, it's exporting with white pixels all over it. What it should be looking like is this.

[image: Text]

Once I got the frames from Blender on to Gimp, the only thing I did was use the Optimize for gifs filter on Gimp and the playback didn't show any of the white pixels. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's almost impossible to tell what has gone wrong here from the images you've shared. You've linked to a video, not a GIF.  What was the original format? How did you get the frames into GIMP?  What are your GIF export settings?

Comment: Those areas are *not* white... they are transparent. You can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/kONmC3s.gif) that they adjust to the background color. I'm not a Blender or Gimp user, but my *guess* would be you've got white set to be transparent somewhere, as opposed to merely a transparent background. (I'm not sure what "video link" @BillyKerr is referring to)

Comment: @Scott if that's so, then it might be something to do with original image format. If the original frames are in Indexed colour, that could easily mess everything up.

Comment: heh.. note the "here" link above.. will open on a black background in Chrome, making the transparency clearly visible when compared to the image here (on a white background). I just realized that some browsers may open the stand alone image also on a white background. Making my link *seem* pointless -- but it's not `:)`

Comment: @Scott - yeah I can see it now, wasn't working before for me. But is now.  You're right, there's transparent pixels inside the coin.  I can see it in Firefox with the Transparent Standalone Images plugin.

Comment: @BillyKerr I wanted to start off with I'm sorry, I have never used this site before today so I'm having some troubles figuring it out. I did figure out the issue and have fixed it, but for the sake of anyone coming behind me I'll do my best to answer your questions.
The original format of the frames prior to trying to export as a GIF out of Gimp were PNGs that were placed in a tmp folder by Blender with the following setting as the output.
![Blender Output Settings](https://i.imgur.com/m1e55Wv.jpg)

-cont-

Comment: I then used the Optimize (for GIf) filter that Gimp offers and exported as a Gif with the following settings.
![Gimp Gif Settings](https://imgur.com/eoGtexw)
What I discovered was that the optimization filter was actually the cause of the issue, if I skipped that step I got a gif that looks like this instead.
![Correct Gif](https://i.imgur.com/gWSWWfF.gif)

Comment: Thank you both though for all the suggestions, I truly appreciate the help!

Comment: @JustaFrootBasket It's *perfectly fine* to answer your own question if you've solved the issue. It may help some future visitor. If you could copy those comments and put them in the actual "answer" area that may be helpful. Then you can mark your answer as "correct" `:)`

Comment: @Scott Ah! Thank you, I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for anyone following behind me, I found the solution that worked for me.
The original format of the frames prior to trying to export as a GIF out of Gimp were PNGs that were placed in a tmp folder by Blender with the following setting as the output.

[image: Blender Output Settings]

I then used the Optimize (for GIf) filter that Gimp offers and exported as a Gif with the following settings.

[image]

What I ended up discovering is that if I skipped the Optimization (for Gifs) filter on Gimp, I got the correct and smooth looking Gif I was after. You can see what I mean at the following link.
[pretty not messed up gif](https://i.imgur.com/gWSWWfF.gif)